# Java Array out of bounds error isn't out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

This code is the relevant portion of my program, and it produces an array out of bounds error, and I can't figure out why.
My error is 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6', with 6 being a random value, at the if statement in randomShot();

```
public class Ai
{
    private int WIDTH;
    private int HEIGHT;

    public Ai(){
        WIDTH=10;
        HEIGHT=10;        
 }

 int[][] board=new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
 Random rand = new Random();

 public void randomShot(){   
    x=rand.nextInt(WIDTH/2);
    y=rand.nextInt(HEIGHT);
    x=x*2;
    if(y%2==0)
    {
        y+=1;
    }
    if(board[x][y]!=0) //java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    {
       randomShot();
    }
}
```

I have noticed that if I use the code

```
int[][] board=new int[10][10];
```

it works perfectly fine. I can't see why this is happening, it's doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: Time to read on order of execution. Field declarations and initializations occur before constructors are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIDTH and HEIGHT are 0 when you are defining board.
Constructor is called after class level variables. For int, the default value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `board` initialization into the constructor. The order of field initializations means the array is declared (and initialized) before the constructor is entered (and thus, the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are zero).

```
private int WIDTH;
private int HEIGHT;

public Ai(){
    WIDTH=10;
    HEIGHT=10;
    board=new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; // <-- here.        
}

int[][] board; // =new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Comment: Better still, move the initialization of `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` *out* of the constructor. `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` should probably be `static final`.

Comment: @EJP, you can't do that, I have other constructors that can set WIDTH and HEIGHT to other values, and yeah I should probably make them static finals.